# Nginx call API to production server

Tags: angularjs, api, nginx

I am working on Angular 1 based web application.
I've deployed a web app with nginx , but couldn't deploy production server in my local env. 
So, I want call API from the production server. For example, 
I am using RestAngular to call API.

```
Restangular.all('api/user/profile').post(mUser)
```

This calls

> localhost:8080/api/user/profile

because I've deployed a web app in localhost:8080.

I want to redirect requests which starts with "/API" to the production server, by config nginx properly.
So, in this case, it should call API server

> http://devprod2api/api/user/profile

Other requests that don't start with "API" should go to:

> http://localhost:8080/...

Is it something possible by config nginx properly? If possible, how can I do that?

Comment: Yes this is is possible. What is your current nginx config? Please post that

Comment: nothing special. I did only port configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you have tried, but this just needs a simple proxy_pass as far as I see. Add below to your nginx config and it should point all API to the other server. It assumes that a host entry is present for `devprod2api`

```
location /api/ {
   proxy_pass http://devprod2api/api/;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks - this helped me out.